How can I get the standard error of the standard deviation of the random intercept in a cumulative linear mixed model using "ordinal" package in R?
# A tibble: 7,500 × 4
   cluster cluster_size     x ordinal_y
     <int>        <int> <dbl> <fct>    
 1       1            1  2.57 4        
 2       1            2  3.59 4        
 3       1            3  2.51 1        
 4       1            4  3.80 3        
 5       1            5  2.84 4        
 6       1            6  2.59 1 

This is my data. I fitted the following model on this data.
mod1 <- ordinal::clmm(ordinal_y ~ x + (1 | cluster),
                      data = dat1,
                      link = "logit")

These are the model result.
mod1

Cumulative Link Mixed Model fitted with the Laplace approximation

formula: ordinal_y ~ x + (1 | cluster)
data:    dat1

 link  threshold nobs logLik   AIC      niter     max.grad
 logit flexible  7500 -7634.28 15278.56 364(1095) 1.45e-02

Random effects:
 Groups  Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 cluster (Intercept) 0.2913   0.5398  
Number of groups:  cluster 150 

Coefficients:
     x 
0.7586 

Thresholds:
   1|2    2|3    3|4 
0.5955 1.1092 1.6108 

The standard deviation of the random error, I get by
mod1$ST is as follows
$cluster
            (Intercept)
(Intercept)   0.5397603

I want the standard error of the of the standard deviation I got for random intercept.
How can I get this?
I tried the function vcov(mod1) and got the follwoing the result.
vcov(mod1)

             1|2          2|3          3|4            x          ST1
1|2 0.0038323677 0.0037161142 0.0036710729 0.0006564625 0.0001370114
2|3 0.0037161142 0.0039511707 0.0038837447 0.0007111263 0.0002270493
3|4 0.0036710729 0.0038837447 0.0041400738 0.0007645963 0.0003178104
x   0.0006564625 0.0007111263 0.0007645963 0.0003864496 0.0001702783
ST1 0.0001370114 0.0002270493 0.0003178104 0.0001702783 0.0058518536

Is ST1*St1 the result I am expecting?

Why do you need the standard error? A confidence interval would appear to be more useful. clmm2 has a profile method that can provide that. I don't know why clmm doesn't.

@Roland clmm is newer version of clmm2 that's why I was tring to go with it but I cant find confidence interval of sigma and also profile takes lot of time in clmm2.
